# getting insufficient permissions for meteor google calendar

Tags: meteor, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm getting insufficient permissions when I trying to access google calendar .I'm using client side code :

> Meteor.loginWithGoogle({requestPermissions: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'], forceApprovalPrompt: true, requestOfflineToken: true});

AND

> Accounts.ui.config({requestPermissions:{google:['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']}, forceApprovalPrompt: {google: true}, requestOfflineToken: {google: true}});

AND  SERVER SIDE

```
Meteor.methods({
 getCalendar: function (arg) {

var user= Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
GoogleApi.get('calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events', {
  user: user,
  params: {
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'timeMin': new Date().toISOString(),
    // 'timeMax': new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)).toISOString(),
    'showDeleted': false,
    'singleEvents': true,
    'orderBy': 'startTime',
    'access_type': 'offline'
  }
}, function (error, result) {
   console.log(result);
 /* if(error){
    console.error(error);
  }*/
});
 },


});
```

> EROR:
>    { error:
>   { errors: [ [Object] ],
>    code: 403,
>    message: 'Insufficient Permission' } }

SO, please tell me how I can access google calendar

Comment: The user must be logged in in order to connect to their Google calendar.  If you have a user id you should have an access token that must be sent with the request.

Comment: I have user id but getting error "Insufficient Permission"

Comment: The user who is logged in doesn't have permission to access calendar check your access token

Comment: How can I make Permission when user try to login with google ?
I mean with meteor js

Comment: you need to use the correct scopes

Comment: How can I add correct scope in meteor ?

Comment: requestPermissions not working for google calendar

Comment: not working
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'],
  requestOfflineToken: true
 });

Please suggest me , how can I access google calendar with meteor google login. Thanks advance

Comment: add your authentication code to your question.   I can't see where you are adding the access token to your call now

Comment: ServiceConfiguration.configurations.upsert(
  { service: 'google' },
  {
    $set: {
      loginStyle: "popup",
      clientId: "xxxxxxxx", 
      secret: "xxxxx"
    }
  }
);

Comment: Meteor.loginWithGoogle({requestPermissions: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'], forceApprovalPrompt: true, requestOfflineToken: true});

AND

Accounts.ui.config({requestPermissions:{google:['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']}, forceApprovalPrompt: {google: true}, requestOfflineToken: {google: true}});

Comment: Please tell me , How can I add correct scope